In blazor, variable current value is not maintained on component re-render
I have defined one variable named ActiveStep, like below:
[Parameter]
public int ActiveStep { get; set; } = 0;

Below, I have shared my sample code.
<button class="e-btn" @onclick="Previous">Previous</button>
<button class="e-btn" @onclick="Next">Next</button>

<MyComponent @ref="_instance" ActiveStep="1">
    <ComponentItems>
        <ComponentItem Label="Cart" IconCss="sf-icon-cart"></ComponentItem >
        <ComponentItem Label="Address" IconCss="sf-icon-user"></ComponentItem >
        <ComponentItem Label="Delivery" IconCss="sf-icon-transport"></ComponentItem >
        <ComponentItem Label="Payment" IconCss="sf-icon-payment"></ComponentItem >
    </ComponentItems>
</MyComponent >

@code {
    private MyComponent _instance { get; set; }
    private async Task Next()
    {
        await _instance.NextStepAsync();
    }

    private async Task Previous()
    {
        await _instance.PreviousStepAsync();
    }

In the above sample, initially the ActiveStep value is set to 1, and when I click the next button, the ActiveStep value is updated from 1 to 2, and then again, when I click the next button, the ActiveStep value should be updated from 2 to 3, but it is reset to the initial value of 1, and after it is updated to 3, each time I click the next or previous button or make any dynamic changes, it gets reset to the initial value of 1.
I have tried without setting the ActiveStep value initially, and it's working fine. The ActiveStep value reset issue only occurs when I set the ActiveStep value initially. I can't find the root cause.

Have you tried binding ActiveStep to a variable and incrementing the variable?

You shouldn't alter Parameters directly.  They are only for intializing the component to a supplied value.

Yes,  ActiveStep="1" will reset it on each render. We don't see the relevant code here.

You could try following workaround.
...
<MyComponent @ref="_instance" >
...
...
    private MyComponent _instance { get; set; } = new MyComponent();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _instance.ActiveStep = 1;
    }
...


Or change the MyComponent.razor like this: 
...
    [Parameter]
    public int InitialStep { get; set; } = 0;

    public int ActiveStep { get; set; } = 0;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ActiveStep = InitialStep;
    }
...

Then in the parent
...
<MyComponent @ref="_instance" InitialStep="1">
...


You can achieve this with binding and without using references into components and calling internal methods.  This uses the built in calls to StateHasChanged associated with UI Events to trigger the necessary component renders to reflect state changes.
Here's a quick demo based on your code that shows updating the step form internally and externally:
<div class=" alert alert-primary m-2">
    @this.ActiveStep
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Advance">Advance</button>
</div>
<div>
    @ChildContent
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int ActiveStep { get; set; } = 0;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ActiveStepChanged { get; set; }

    private Task Advance()
    {
        this.ActiveStepChanged.InvokeAsync(this.ActiveStep + 1);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Previous">Previous</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Next">Next</button>

<MyComponent @bind-ActiveStep="_currentStep">
    Some Content
</MyComponent>

@code {
    private int _currentStep = 1;

    private Task Next()
    {
        _currentStep++;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task Previous()
    {
        _currentStep--;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

